# Sql join and pivot to get category totals

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have these tables.

**Main table**

```
[key]   [CategoryID]
AAAA    100
BBBB    100
CCCC    101
DDDD    102
EEEE    201
FFFF    202
GGGG    202
etc.
```

**Category lookup**

```
[CategoryID]    [Category]      [Subcategory]
100             Category1       Subcategory1
101             Category1       Subcategory2
102             Category1       Subcategory3
103             Category1       Subcategory4
200             Category2       SubcategoryA
201             Category2       SubcategoryB
202             Category2       SubcategoryC
etc.
```

**Status lookup**

```
[StatusID]  [Description]
0           New
500         Accepted
501         Rejected
```

**Status history**

```
[key]   [StatusID]      [date]
AAAA    0               2017-01-01
BBBB    0               2017-01-01
CCCC    0               2017-01-01
DDDD    0               2017-01-01
EEEE    0               2017-01-01
FFFF    0               2017-01-01
GGGG    0               2017-01-01
AAAA    500             2017-01-02
BBBB    501             2017-01-02
EEEE    501             2017-01-02
FFFF    500             2017-01-02
BBBB    500             2017-01-03
EEEE    500             2017-01-03
etc.
```

I'd like to get a monthly summary of the results (which is emailed out). Right now I'm building the summary table in the code. I'd like to learn how to do it in SQL, but I don't really know where to start.

Final table where the totals are based on the last [Status History] value and ordered by [Total] DESC.

```
[Category]  [Subcategory]   [New]   [Accepted]  [Rejected]  [Total]
Category1   Subcategory1    13      8           2           23
Category2   Subcategory3    10      4           6           20
Category1   Subcategory2    5       8           4           17
```

I've tried to look at PIVOT to do this, but I don't understand how to do it with the joins and with getting only the last status history value.

Comment: What do you mean by "last [Status History] value"? As in the most recent status history for each `[key]`?

Comment: @PatJones Yes, the most recent status history for each [key].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after. I recreated your data and tested it out, but I definitely had to make one or two assumptions about the relationships involved. Try it and let me know:

```
select Category, 
       Subcategory,
       sum(case when description = 'New' then 1 else 0 end) as New,
       sum(case when description = 'Accepted' then 1 else 0 end) as Accepted,
       sum(case when description = 'Rejected' then 1 else 0 end) as Rejected,
       count(*) as Total
from
(select tB.Category, tB.Subcategory, status_lookup.Description
 from status_history inner join (select my_key, max(status_date) as lastdate
                                 from status_history
                                 group by my_key) tA on status_history.my_key = tA.my_key
                                                        and status_history.status_date = tA.lastdate
                    inner join status_lookup on status_history.StatusID = status_lookup.StatusID
                    inner join (select main.my_key, category_lookup.Category, category_lookup.Subcategory
                                from main inner join category_lookup on main.CategoryID = category_lookup.CategoryID) tB on status_history.my_key = tB.my_key) tC
group by Category, Subcategory
```

I renamed your `[key]` column `my_key`, and called the tables `main`, `category_lookup`, `status_lookup`, and `status_history` respectively.

Comment: Wow, that's intense! I managed to translate it to the "real world" and it looks good. I added a WHERE clause into the SELECT statement that's inside the INNER JOIN of tB (basically a WHERE clause on main). It looked like the correct spot. Thank you for your help. Hopefully I can use this to write better SQL statements in the future.

Comment: You're welcome. There are usually many ways to go out these things, but since you have four tables and are doing some aggregating and max finding, a lot of joins will naturally be involved. If it works for you, feel free to mark this as the answer, thanks!

Comment: re: mark this as the answer - figured it out and marked it. :)